# Wi-Fi is not working in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, networking, realtek-wireless

Here is the information gathered about my wi-fi using the script provided by you guys here at AskUbuntu: http://paste.ubuntu.com/12733543/

I use a laptop dualboot Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

I just moved to a hostel and the wifi is provided by the hostel.

In the first few days, I had no problem using the wifi. However, I noticed wifi connection problem since yesterday and it is turning on and off. In other words, the connection would break at any time. I tried to use Windows 7 and there were no wi-fi problem. I could stream movies smoothly.

Could you please help me out? For now I use iphone hotspot shared via cable to go to internet.

Comment: Everything looks OK so try disabling IPV6...

Answer (score -3):

I had the same problem.
I don't know how to solve it on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. This is probably the fault of the kernel 3.16.
The problem arises on any distribution based on the kernel 3.16 and Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Linux Mint 17.x etc).

Upgrade to Ubuntu 15.04 and kernel 3.19 solves the problem.